# Selling my bitcoins with 10% extra profit. How is that possible?

Tags: bitcoind

I found website where I'm selling bitcoins for paypal almost around 1 month now. They are giving me +10% to all rates on the market. I'm selling to them, than depositing it to btc-e, buy bitcoins there and than selling them again. 
How is that possible that they can afford +10%? I've contacted support at the beginning, the said that they have a lot of PP in stock from their business websites, and also they are selling btc with higher rates so they can cover this 10%. Is it sound reliable? Check it by yourselves - www.hiribi.com

PS. Moderator please do not delete this post because of this link, if it's against rules just delete this link and leave my question, I need answers. Thanks.

Comment: This feels more like a business question than a Bitcoin question.  You are essentially asking "how can a company buy X at a loss?"  The fact that X in this case is bitcoin doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If something sounds or looks like a scam, it probably is one. No business will buy bulk of anything and pay 10% on top of the regular price.

Probably they can process small amounts to lure someone to send them larger ones. Then they just can say, that's not their transaction which you send BTC to.

*Omitting the fact, that this is probably a fake account.*